# How to make Square dotted border

Tags: html, css

I want make a Square spaced dotted border, Can anyone please tell how to make those dots **Square**, Like,

[image]

Here is my code,  Please help me.

```css
.dots{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 10%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: left;
  background-size: 1px 10px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
div {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="dots">Dotted border</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your example:

```
<div class="dots"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
.dots{
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color: #f3c4f8;
  position: relative;
}
.dots::before {
  content: "";
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background-color: #ab43ba;
  position: absolute;
  left:10px;
}
```

Also [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjj5mu4p/2/) link for test.

Comment: Mam your answer its quite right, but not like what i want, I want a square dotted border. If I put this then I have to put many div repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your CSS, need fine tuning :)

```
.dots:after{
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 1%, red 0%, red 20%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0) 0%);
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 6px 30px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  content: '';
}

.dots:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 1%, red 0%, red 20%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0) 0%);
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 6px 30px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  content: '';
}

div {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="dots">Dotted border</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I want, But I'm vote up this answer, Cause I got the concept from this answer, Thanks for Helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border: 2px dotted black">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found another simple way to do it, (almost) cross-browser that i want to share.

**'dotted' is not cross-browser! The border value 'dotted' is round in Firefox and squared in Chrome. And they are behaving strange when resizing.**

1. Make a simple SVG file with the two colours as squared  elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg class="it-dotted-line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="8">
  <rect width="4" height="4" style="fill:#F4EDF4"></rect>
  <rect x="4" width="4" height="4" style="fill:#B489B4"></rect>
</svg>
```

*The height is 8 as well so the image is squared - easier to work with.*

2. Save it as a .svg file and upload it to your webhotel so you can use it in `border-image`.

*Just put the code in your code-editor and save it as a .svg file.*

3. The CSS:

```
.dots {
  -o-border-image: url(/svg-dotted.svg) 25% repeat; /* Opera 11-12.1 */
  -webkit-border-image: url(/svg-dotted.svg) 25% repeat ; /* Safari 3.1-5 */   
  border-image: url(/svg-dotted.svg) 25% repeat;
  border-width: 0px; // Only for top border - remove others
  border-top-width: 10px; 
  border-style: solid;
}
```

### Result (top of a footer):

[image]

**Note:** Internet Explorer 10, and earlier versions, do not support the border-image property.